# Вывод данных авторизованного пользователя

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server, foreach

Необходимо в форме "мой профиль" вывести данные того пользователя который прошёл авторизацию,я сделал вывод данных, но у меня выводит данные только самого первого пользователя, даже если ты заходишь под другим.

Вывод данных в форме мой профиль:

```
   DataBase dataBase = new DataBase();
    public MyProfile()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Подключение к БД
        string connection = @"Data Source=localhost; Initial Catalog=Магазин_книг;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter data = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * From Покупатели", con);
        DataSet ds_shop = new DataSet("Магазин_книг");
        data.Fill(ds_shop, "Покупатели");
        DataTable table;
        table = ds_shop.Tables["Покупатели"];
        DataRow row;
        row = table.Rows[0]; // foreach(])

        // Заполнение полей

        textBoxName.Text = row["Имя"].ToString();
        textBoxFamil.Text = row["Фамилия"].ToString();
        textBoxOtch.Text = row["Отчество"].ToString();
        textBoxTelphone.Text = row["Номер_телефона"].ToString();
        labelGorod.Text = row["Город"].ToString();
        labelDateRoj.Text = row["Дата_рождения"].ToString();
        labelNomerKart.Text = row["Номер_карты"].ToString();
        labelBalance.Text = row["Баланс"].ToString();
        labelSkidka.Text = row["Скидка"].ToString();

        con.Close();
    }
```

на сколько я понимаю в строке (row = table.Rows[0];) нужно как то использовать оператор foreach, но не могу понять как, помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: 1) не пишите свой код в конструкторе формы, используйте обработчик события `Form.Load`, чтобы он появился, надо дважды ткнуть по пустому месту на форме в дизайнере формы. 2) чтобы достать нужную запись из таблицы, нужно условие, критерий, которому она соответствует. Как определить, какая именно запись правильная, что там чему должно быть равно?

Comment: Не правильно понимаете, нужно выбрать из бд только нужного "покупателя", т.е. изменить нужно вот эту часть ```"SELECT * From Покупатели"```

Comment: SqlDataAdapter data = new SqlDataAdapter($"SELECT * From Покупатели where Логин = '{loginuser}' and  Пароль = '{passworduser}'", con); То есть так?

Comment: В идеале, сделать это через параметры, но и так тоже будет работать. Также, оборачивайте SqlConnection в using - тогда не придётся самостоятельно закрывать соединение

Comment: Frehzy, не совсем вас понял

Comment: **Не храните пароли в базе в открытом виде, используйте хэширование**, а по поводу `using` - [Использование объектов, реализующих IDisposable](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects)

Comment: Касаемо параметров - используйте параметрический запрос https://metanit.com/sharp/adonet/2.9.php. Насчёт using вам ответили выше. Касаемо хэширования, о котором написал выше aepot: пароли в бд должны храниться в зашифрованном виде. При обращении в бд, вы шифруете по тому же алгоритму введённый пароль и сравниваете **зашифрованные** пароли.  Полезная статья про шифрование - https://habr.com/ru/post/254909/

Comment: Сперва осуществляется логин (вход) пользователя. При этом вы делаете запрос `Select ... where ...`. После чего сохраняете `id` пользователя. Далее работаете с этим `id`.